# Updating a database on DataGrid when query is made up of inner join

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid, inner-join

Am doing the coding in C#

My MySQL Database consist of 5 tables namely

- student
- personal_information
- academics_table
- engineering
- aggregate

Each table has a common column branch_code

The query that is binding to the DataGrid through a DataTable is:

```
SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN personal_information USING ( branch_code ) INNER JOIN academics_table USING ( branch_code ) INNER JOIN engineering USING ( branch_code ) INNER JOIN AGGREGATE USING ( branch_code );
```

I need to update the changes made in the DataGrid to the database. Please tell me how it can be done.

Comment: I think this needs to be done manually for each column in the gridview, unless anyone would enlighten me too!